# curves that avoid intersection with faces

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, procedural

Im trying to make curves that move around solid faces to simulate vine growth with geometry nodes. I've tried displacing the curves points with the geometry proximity node but to no avail. Is there a way to procedurally build the path of curves and move them away from intersecting a face? I added 2 pictures. First one is what I am currently facing and the second one is what I am tring to achieve.

[image: what i have right now]

[image: What i would like to have]

Comment: i am pretty sure that you cannot use geometry proximity here. Raycast is the key to success - i think